# "This boys hat": Ambiguity of demonstative with possessive

Tags: ambiguity, possessives, demonstratives

> A.    [This boy]’s hat is cute.
>
> B.    This [boys’ hat] is cute.

In sentence A, "this" modifies "boy," and in sentence B, "this" modifies "boy's hat," as the brackets show.

**Questions**

What is this potential ambiguity called? Is it an issue with possessives?

Is this ambiguity solved merely by the placement of the apostrophe in such cases?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, this is not about any boy or hat; it is about an inherent structural ambiguity, in general. "Boy" and "hat" are simply dummy terms to fill grammatical categories, like in algebra. Perhaps then it would have been clearer if I had said something like: A. [This A]'s Q is Y;  B. This [A's Q] is Y.

Comment: How about using a possessive noun in common use:  "pitcher's mound".  If I tell the groundskeeper "Move this pitcher's mound," even if a specific pitcher is standing next to me, he won't parse it "(this pitcher's) mound", since individual pitchers do not own their own mounds.  Now if I said "Move this pitcher's glove," he'd look to see whose it was, because a "pitcher's glove" is not a "thing"; pitchers don't wear special gloves.  However, catchers do wear special gloves; if I switched to "catcher's glove," then problem; it could be either!  Context often guides, but sometimes, it's ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

It is only ambiguous when spoken. When read in text, there is a clear distinction between a case of a singular possessive noun [This boy's hat]; And the second case which is an example of a plural possessive adjectival-noun [This boys' hat]. [Boys'] is no longer the object being modified by [This] because it has taken the function of an adjective and is used, here, to describe what type of hat (a hat for boys as opposed to a hat for girls, for instance). Since we're using the plural of boys as our adjectival noun, which ends in the letter ess, we can't very well tack on an ['s] to indicate possession without making it look even more ridiculous -- [This boys's hat]. That just doesn't sound phonetically appealing -- so we just drop the second [s] and leave it at [s'] to indicate a plural noun (pretending to be an adjective) in its possessive form (also applies to singular nouns that happen to end with the letter [s] and their possessive forms).

I don't know that we call this type of ambiguity anything since, again, it's only phonetically ambiguous... Which I suppose would make it a

[**homophone**](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=homophone) - a word that is pronounced the same as another word but differs in meaning, and may differ in spelling.